# MS MVC Razor Model Attribute Control Type Boolean

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I thought this one would be so simple.

The only attribute that defines a property for for a control (textbox) is

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)].
```

If a property is a string (textbox), life is good.

Looking at a property that is a Boolean.

Technically the control could be a:

- Checkbox (true false, and even null)
- Radio Button (true, false, and even null)

If, theoretically of course, I want to define the HTML control type (checkbox or radio button) in the Model like:

```
[ControlType(ControlType.Checkbox)]
```

or

```
[ControlType(ControlType.RadioButton)]
```

Is this even possible? Then when the *.cshtml is generated is at least knows what type of control (checkbox or RadioButton) to initially produce.

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Why do you want to define it in the model? That attribute on strings just define whether the string represents a single line or multiple lines of text, not what control should be used to render it.  Determining how to display the data is the view's job.  Also a radio button is used to choose one option from a set of options, so defining it on a single boolean value doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Use `EditorFor()` to generate the form control in your view. It will respect all `[DataType]` attributes ad take int account the property type (for example, a checkbox will be generated for `bool` properties. And you an use `[UIHint]` define specific templates for a property.

Comment: For end-users that have no concept of "null", a boolean using a checkbox might not be clear to them  checked / unchecked / greyed.  

So radio buttons such as Yes / No / Unknown can be a bit clearer to them.